# how to three corner radius of Image view

Tags: objective-c, io

[image]

how to draw image corner radius only three corner look at my image.
please tell me how can i do this..? thanks in advance.

Comment: better to use image if only you need show a button or image. otherwise uibezierpath is option to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:YourImageView.bounds
                                     byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = YourImageView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    YourImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Edit:

```
    YourImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    YourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    YourImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
```

Make sure you are importing `QuartzCore` framework:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: yes its work but after that i am given border color of imageview but border not seen..

Comment: Try after changing maskLayer frame as per your requirement@NileshParmar

Comment: okay, it should work but now you have to find out what causing that@NileshParmar

Comment: Enjoy Coding!@NileshParmar